# opening applications from a webpage

Tags: javascript, windows, internet-explorer, hta

I use the following to open notepad from a webpage:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Application Executer</title>
    <HTA:APPLICATION ID="oMyApp" 
        APPLICATIONNAME="Application Executer" 
        BORDER="no"
        CAPTION="no"
        SHOWINTASKBAR="yes"
        SINGLEINSTANCE="yes"
        SYSMENU="yes"
        SCROLL="no"
        WINDOWSTATE="normal">
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
        function RunFile() {
        WshShell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
        WshShell.Run("C:\Program Files\Notepad++\notepad++.exe", 1, false);
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="button" value="Run Notepad" onclick="RunFile();"/>
</body>
</html>
```

This works.

When I try with applications, notepad++, dreamweaver etc it fails.

In the console the error is flagged on line

```
WshShell.Run("C:\Program Files\Notepad++\notepad++.exe", 1, false);
```

Making me think the error is with the type of application

Is there a list of applications that can be opened using this method? How are Microsoft applications, word/excel and other applications opened using this method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two probs:

1. If the path contains spaces you need to surround it with quotes
2. This is JavaScript so `\` in a string is a special character used to indicate escape sequences, to put a `\` in a string it must be escaped itself as `\\`

Use:

```
 WshShell.Run('"C:\\Program Files\\Notepad++\\notepad++.exe"', 1, false);
```